# Group By Date in Rethinkdb is slow

Tags: rethinkdb

I am trying group by date like following for total count

`r.db('analytic').table('events').group([r.row('created_at').inTimezone("+08:00").year(), r.row('created_at').inTimezone("+08:00").month(),r.row('created_at').inTimezone("+08:00").day()]).count()`

However, it slow and  it took over 2 seconds for 17656 records.

Is there any way to get data faster for group by date ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to group and count all the records, it's going to have to read every record, so the speed will be determined mostly by your hardware rather than the specific query.  If you only want one particular range of dates, you could get that much faster with an indexed `between` query.